Generate Dark Colors Only in React and JS
I have an <Avatar/> component and the text inside of it is color white,
How do I make sure that its background color is dark so the text can be seen since its dynamically generated?
Codesandbox -----> CLICK HERE
CODE:
  const colors = useMemo(() => {
    const randomColors = persons.map(() => `#${Math.floor(Math.random() * 16777215).toString(16)}`);
    return randomColors;
  }, [persons]);


will lowering brightness work? if yes, i can create  script for that


The random value for each colour component (red, green, blue) is from 0-255. You need to limit to 0 - 127 to ensure that the generated colours are darker.

padStart(2, '0') ensures that each component has two digits in hexadecimal form


utils.js
export function randomColors(persons) {
  const darkColors = persons.map(() => {
        // Generate each color component in the lower half (0-127) of the 0-255 range
        const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 128).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
        const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 128).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
        const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 128).toString(16).padStart(2, '0');
        return `#${r}${g}${b}`;
  });
  return darkColors;
}

Inside your react component.
const colors = useMemo(() => {
    return randomColors(persons)
}, [persons]);

CODESANDBOX

@Joseph Sure, if you want to use it in multiple places, you can move the logic to a util function, and use it inside the useMemo hook.

@Joseph, just done, please check.

@Joseph You are welcome, sure, but could you please create a new question with this, as it is out of this question's scope, and share the link with me?
